# Is there any PPA that follow the latest Intel Opensource Driver For Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, ppa, intel-graphics

Intel have [opensource driver source repositories](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2011Q3.html)

The question is, is there any PPA that try to create deb package from the repositories that follow the latest version?

Comment: what type of intel graphics - sandy bridge?

Answer (score 2):

“xorg crack pushers” team provides unstable versions, they also update other open source and proprietary drivers.

[ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

If you want something more secure or less "edger" try the PPA maintained by Oibaf. They provide only FOSS drivers updates and `libdrm`.

[ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

Comment: `/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers` only support 11.04 and above

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a separate PPA dedicated to Intel graphic drivers. The Ubuntu-x team maintains it.

[ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/intel-graphics-updates [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/intel-graphics-updates) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

Comment: This repository does not seem to be maintained anymore, last update was in 2012.